# changing margin value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below code if there is error msg. then the margin top of login form should be "0" and for the first error msg margin top should be "70px".

```
<span class="portlet-msg-error"> You have entered invalid data. Please try again. </span>

<span class="portlet-msg-error"> Authentication failed. Please try again.</span>

<div class="login-form" style="margin-top: 70px;"> Form Display here </div>
```

Answer (score 16):

```
$('.login-form').css({'margin-top':'0px'}); // Login form
$('.portlet-msg-error:first').css({'margin-top':'70px'}); // Error Message
```

*It may be `marginTop`, I forget if jQuery can accept the full name or if you have to camelCase it when there are hyphens*

**EDIT** Just checked, `margin-top` [seems to work](http://www.jsfiddle.net/g5Qxe/)

Comment: Both `"margin-top":` and `marginTop:` work. jQuery will convert the camelCase version to the full CSS name.

Comment: Those are two identical lines? and are incorrect margins for login box (based on the question).

Comment: @Box9: Thank you for confirming. ;-) -- @MarcusWhybrow: Not any more. heh, just high-sign it's time for me to go to bed. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if(error)
{
 $(".login-form").css("margin-top", "0");
 $(".portlet-msg-error:first").css("margin-top", "70px");
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect the pseudo class is `:first-child` and not `:first`

Comment: Nope, first-child will look for the child of the selector .portlet-msg-error element, here we are looking for the first  .portlet-msg-error hence first is correct. Verify http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Comment: I would however argue, that the intended goal looks to put in some extra margin for the first error box in an arbitrary list. You would want this to be applied to **all** instances where this occurs, and not just the first on the page.

Comment: OP wanted to set margin for first error box, hence did not want to assume anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in CSS:

```
.login-form {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.portlet-msg-error:first-child {
    margin-top: 70px;
}
```

The same in jQuery would be:

```
$('.login-form').css('margin-top', '0px');
$('.portlet-msg-error:first-child').css('margin-top', '70px');
```

So you see there is no real reason to use jQuery in this case.

Comment: @Ritesh Do you know how to accept and answer on Stack Overflow? It will close the question.